# My screen keeps shutting off after a few minutes of not using

Tags: windows-7, windows

I then have to push the unlock key to get back on

Comment: we need more details... like have you done anything (software/hardware changes, etc) recently with your computer?  If improved, flag to be considered for reopening by a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open *Control Panel*, press *Hardware and Sound*, then under *Power Options* press *Require a password when the computer wakes*.
2. In the lower half of the screen, under *Password protection on wakeup*, you may have to press *Change settings that are currently unavailable.  If not, ignore this step.
3. Select *Don't require a password*.
4. Press *Save changes* and close the window.